# AngularJS - Attempted to assign to readonly property inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have object eg.

```
$scope.types = [{id: 1, name: 'test', items: [{qty: 1}, {qty: 2}]}, {id: 2, name: 'test2'}];
```

etc...

i'm using angular's ng-repeat to loop through the object.

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types">
<div ng-repeat="item in type.items">
<input type="text" ng-model="item.qty" />
</div>
</div>
```

Items can be added to the type.items object dynamically, which works completely fine.

Once saved, it uses sqlite to retrieve the items, which works fine and populates the inputs with the quantities entered.

I can amend the quantities fine on the browser, android just not iOS. I get the error in console:

```
Error: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
   assign$$writeModelToScope@file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/.../testapp.app/www/bower_components/angular/angular.js:28534:22
```

I'm using safari web inspector to inspect the application on the device which is how i get this console error.

Comment: There is just one code snippet left: How do you assign your types-objects with those values coming from the sqlite-db?

Comment: This was the issue. I had to use angular.copy() on the object returned from the db, which then worked!